# How to put facebook login button?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Hi I want to put Facebook login in my website but it shows blank page. What can i do?
i tried following code.

**fb.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId:'myappid',
    status:true,
    cookie:true,
    xfbml:true
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();
    } else {
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };


  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>

<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: console error, did you check that?